# How can I permanently bcc: an email address (other than myself) in Apple Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, monterey

How can I permanently bcc: an email address (other than myself) in Apple Mail? I found the following tip, however this does not work with mail 15.0 (Monterey):

Enter in terminal:

1. defaults read com.apple.mail UserHeaders
2. defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Bcc" = "bcc@url.com"; }' (replace bcc@url.com with actual bcc-address)

to check: defaults read com.apple.mail UserHeaders

to delete: defaults delete com.apple.mail UserHeaders

Thank you!

Comment: Could you share the output you see when you ran `defaults read com.apple.mail UserHeaders`? I am on Mail v16.0 and this method works for me.